# Difference between the two implementions of strStr()

Tags: c, algorithm

I was doing this implement strStr() practice from LeetCode:

> Implement strStr().
>
> Return the index of the first occurrence of needle in haystack, or -1
>   if needle is not part of haystack.

My first solution is like below :

```
int strStr(char* haystack, char* needle) {
char * hay = haystack;
char * haytmp ;
char * nd = needle;
if(!*nd)
    return 0;
while(*hay){
    haytmp = hay;
    while(*haytmp==*nd && *haytmp && *nd){
        haytmp++;
        nd++;       
    }
    if(*nd){
        hay++;
        nd = needle;
    }
    else{
        return strlen(haystack) - strlen(hay);

    }
}
return -1;
}
```

It took 440ms to pass the cases. I noticed that the fasted solution only takes 4ms which is 100 times faster than my solution, is like below :

```
int strStr(char* haystack, char* needle) {
char *hay = haystack;
char * nd = needle;
char * haytmp = hay;
if(!*needle)
    return 0;
while(*hay){        
    if(*haytmp==*nd){
        haytmp++;
        nd++;
        if(*nd=='\0')
            return strlen(haystack)-strlen(hay);
        if(*haytmp=='\0')
            return -1;
    }else{        
        hay++;
        haytmp = hay;
        nd=needle;
    }
}
return -1;
}
```

I can see the difference is that I used an extra while loop. 
But I think the two implementations have same time complexities.
Why is there a huge difference in efficiency between them?

*Sorry for my bad English. Hope you can understand my description. :)

Comment: The second implementation returns -1 without completing the while loop on line 14. Yours has to still scroll hay. Anyway the difference is too wide to be just that. It could depend on the test cases.

Comment: @Attersson That is exactly the reason! I add ' if(!*haytmp) return -1;' to my code and it becomes as fast as the other one. Thank you very much. I didn't notice that.

Comment: Alright I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second implementation avoids evaluating several cases that have no chance of matching with these lines:

```
if(*haytmp=='\0')
     return -1;
```

By returning failure when what is left of the haystack is shorter than the needle and cannot possibly match.

Your code still keeps traversing and comparing the short end of the haystack even though there are not enough characters left to match the needle.

Comment: Yes, I add this to my implementation and it works as fast as the other one. Thank you very much.